# AppendChild a element above a cerain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So i have a div element which will be filled **dynamically** with others divs using the **appendChild** Method, this should display a list. The User is now able to sort that list with the JqueryUI **Sortable** option.
I also added some sortable option attribues like follows:
**Options:**

```
$("#NameContainer").sortable("option", "axis", "y");
$("#NameContainer").sortable( "option", "containment", "parent" );
```

**LIST**

```
<div id="NameContainer" class="ui-widget">
  <div id="Name_1">John</div>
  <div id="Name_2">Jack</div>
  <div id="Name_3">Charlie</div>
  <div id="Name_4">Sawyer</div>
  <div id="Name_5">Yin</div>
  <div id="Name_6">Ben</div>
</div>
```

Now comes my problem. The appendChild always inserts the new div at the bottom of the container but i want to to add some space at the bottom of to the Container Div with a "br" or something like that. I want to add that space to make sure that when the user sorts the last item of that list it will get sorted correctly because the "containment" bounds sometimes wont allow to sort under the last item.

```
<div id="NameContainer" class="ui-widget">
      <div id="Name_1">John</div>
      <div id="Name_2">Jack</div>
      <div id="Name_3">Charlie</div>
      <div id="Name_4">Sawyer</div>
      <div id="Name_5">Yin</div>
      <div id="Name_6">Ben</div>
      <br><!--SPACEHOLDER-->
    </div>
```

So here comes my Question is there away to appendChild above a certain element?
 Like a "br" "div" or "p"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of appendChild:

Please note I have used random value to add in div as I don't have your dynamic value.

check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dqx9nbcy/

```
  <div id="NameContainer" class="ui-widget">
     <div id="divspacer"></div> 
   </div>
   <button id="btn">ADD Element</button>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
       var parentnode = document.getElementById("NameContainer");
       var existnode = document.getElementById("divspacer");
       var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
       var newName = document.createElement("div");   
       newName.setAttribute("id", rand); 
       newName.setAttribute("value", rand);
       newName.setAttribute("class","ui-widget-content");
       newName.innerHTML = rand; 
       parentnode.insertBefore(newName,existnode);
    });
});
```

Comment: mhhh your example works, but not with my dynamic div that will get added.

Comment: The divs are getting added like so: `var newName = document.createElement("div");
  newName.setAttribute("id", NameId);
  newName.setAttribute("value", sName);
  newName.setAttribute("class","ui-widget-content");
  newName.innerHTML = sName;` then follows the inser Part: `newName.insertBefore("#divspacer")`

Comment: You are using javascript. The syntax is different for javascript and jQuery. I have updated my ans. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

refer http://api.jquery.com/appendto/ but you need to make sure that your are targeting right tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code snippet.

**HTML Snippet**

```
<div id="NameContainer" class="ui-widget">
 <div id="Name1">Name1</div> 
 <div id="Name2">Name2</div>
 <div id="Name3">Name3</div>
 <div id="Name4">Name4</div>
 <br>
 <br>
 </div>
```

**Javascript Snippet**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
       var containerDiv= $("#NameContainer");
       var childList = containerDiv.children("div");
       var newElementid = childList.length;
       var newName = document.createElement("div");   
       newName.setAttribute("id", "Name"+(newElementid+1)); 
       newName.setAttribute("value", "Name"+(newElementid+1));
       newName.setAttribute("class","ui-widget-content");
       newName.innerHTML = "Name"+(newElementid+1); 
       $(childList[childList.length-1]).after(newName);
    });
});
```

This is specific to a situation where there are some elements in the initial list. The same can be modified for dynamic list of implementation by validating that `childList.length` is != 0 before using the same.